# how to use abstract arguments to show uniqueness and existence of a solution to an IVP?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I'm preparing for my exam and doing old tests to prepare and I get the following problematic question:

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R}^{1+1} \to \mathbb{R}^1$ be given by, $f(t,x) = \frac{1}{e^x}$.

Show with abstract arguments that there exists (locally) a unique solution, $h_\mathcal{l} \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, to the IVP: $ y'(t) = f(t,y(t)), \ y(1) = 0.$

I've been told that it's enough to check whether $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^{d+1})$ holds and if $||f(t,x)|| \leq C||x||$, $\forall t \in [t,x] \in \mathbb{R}^{d+1} \ \text{for} \ C \in \mathbb{R}_+$ holds, and then we have the answer from a general result from the course. My problem is that I'm not quite sure how to check these assumptions.

Comment: You should be able to say something about the differentiability. The linear bound should be more complicated to prove, as it is wrong.

Comment: Since it says in the assignment, that in this case, it's only a local solution wouldn't it suffice to show that $|\frac{1}{e^x}| \leq C |x| \forall x \in [1,\infty)$?

Comment: That is completely useless for the stated purpose. Global linear boundedness in the form $\|f(t,x)\|\le C\|x\|+D$ can be used to prove global existence. Local uniqueness requires a Lipschitz condition or continuous differentiability.